# How do I update libpng in my project

Tags: android, google-play

I received this message from Google after sending my app to Play Store, I searched for a solution but I don't know how i can apply it in my case: I don't know how to update `libpng`.

I downloaded the the new version of `libpng` but i don't know how to update it in my project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you build your APK. But suppose you build with Gradle in Android Studio.

- find the link to the libpng in your gradle file (probably in a `compile` line)
- replace the old version with the new version in that line.

If you want more help, you will have to give more details about how you build your APK in the question.